# jQuery FileManager Recommendations

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, file-manager

I am looking for a filemanager to use in a jQuery project I am working on.
What are the most recommended jQuery FileManager plugins?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this;

open-source file manager for web, written in JavaScript using jQuery UI.

http://www.webappers.com/2012/04/27/open-source-file-manager-for-web-using-jquery-ui/

10 jQuery Based File Manager Plugins

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-file-manager-plugins/